# How does Cascade Layers works with Media query?

Tags: css

I understand the essence of creating a cascade layer in CSS is to organize and manage styles in a modular and reusable way. By using cascade layers, I can group related styles together and apply them to specific components or sections of a website.

But what I don't understand is its use with media queries, as with this example below, I am expecting the layer mobile style to be applied for max-width: 768px but it does when the screen width is wider than 768px.

Again I would love to know if it should be used in recent projects as it's relatively a new feature in CSS and does not have old browsers support.

Can anybody shed more light on this, please?

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    @layer mobile;
}


  
@layer desktop {
    /* CSS rules for desktop layout */
    .header {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 120px;
        font-size: 120px;
    }

    body{
        background-color: white;
    }
}



@layer mobile {
    /* CSS rules for mobile layout */
    .header {
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    .content {
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    body{
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Layers are evaluated in the order that they are first mentioned, with the later mentioned layers taking precedence in the same way that later rules take precedence over earlier rules when they have the same specificity.

So

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    @layer mobile;
}
```

at the top means that "mobile" is the first mentioned layer when the screen is 768px wide or less.

So on small screens, the order is "mobile", "desktop", and as later mentioned layers have the precedence, the styles of the "desktop" layer are applied to the page.

When the screen is larger than 768px, the @media rule is ignored, so the mentioned order of the layers is "desktop", "mobile", and the styles of the "mobile" layer are the ones applied.

---

To fix, just use min-width instead of max-width. Then on larger width browsers, the "mobile" layer will be "pulled up" to before the "desktop" layer, and the then later "desktop" layer will be the styles that are applied.

Or, if you want to use max-width to avoid the risk of the screen width being in the sub-pixel gap, you can declare all the layers at the top like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    @layer desktop;
}
@layer mobile, desktop;
```

So that it is the "desktop" layer that is "pulled up" to before the "mobile" layer on small screens.